How can I check network connectivity from Android reliably?
I am trying to figure out how I can make my app periodically check if the device is connected to a network. I have the following code for network checking:
public class NetworkHelper {

    private static final String TAG = "NetworkHelper";
    
    public static boolean isDeviceConnectedToNetwork(Context context) {
        boolean isConnected = false;
    
        try {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
                 context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
            Log.d(TAG, "Checking network: " + isConnected);
            return isConnected;
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

The following code for calling NetworkHelper periodically:
public class MQTTConnectionFragment extends Fragment {

    ...

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        networkCheckerThread = new HandlerThread("NetworkCheckerThread");
        networkCheckerThread.start();
    
        networkCheckerHandler = new Handler(networkCheckerThread.getLooper());
        networkCheckerRunnable = () -> {
            Log.d(TAG, "Running network check");
            boolean isConnected = NetworkHelper.isDeviceConnectedToNetwork(getContext());
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {
                 if (isConnected) {
                     connectionBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                     disconnectButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                     loadingWheel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                     noNetworkTextView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                 } else {
                     connectionBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                     disconnectButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                     loadingWheel.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                     noNetworkTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 }
                  networkCheckerHandler.postDelayed(networkCheckerRunnable,
                                                isConnected ? 5000 : 3000);
             });
        };
        
        networkCheckerHandler.postDelayed(networkCheckerRunnable, 200);
        
        return view;
    
    }
    ...
}

The log keeps reporting that I always have connection, even when I turn Wi-Fi off. Can it be because I am using an AVD? Or is it something with my code I am not seeing? I don't have access to a physical device for a little while and thought testing on the AVD would be fine.

Take below code as reference to observe connection state.
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.Network;
import android.net.NetworkCapabilities;
import android.net.NetworkRequest;
import android.os.Build;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class NetworkUtil {

    public static void registerNetworkCallback(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkRequest.Builder builder = new NetworkRequest.Builder();
        builder.addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET);

        connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(
                builder.build(),
                new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                        // Network is available
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onLost(Network network) {
                        // Network is lost
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}


Doesn't seem to work. What I did:
Create the class you provided above, made it so that it sends a LocalBroadcast "NETWORK_CONNECTION_STATUS", which is received by one of my Fragments (so I can have visual feedback). However, when I turn off Wi-Fi, the connection loss is not reflected properly. FYI, I am still using an AVD, could that be a problem?

Put logs in both in onAvailable and onLost callbacks and see if the logs are printed.

I did just that, they are not executed unfortunately.

I have tested in my device and the code is working. Don't forget to add this permission.      

try using BroadcastReceiver for listening to network connectivity changes. for reference android-listening-to-connectivity-changes-the-correct-way

I've tried your approach but unfortunately it also yields the same result.

You might be getting the unexpected results because the network environment on emulators is simulated.
Could you please make sure you have the necessary permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />```

I have all the necessary permissions declared already.

have you registered the broadcast reciever inside your onCreate method in your activity class?

Indeed this was a mistake that I made in the beginning, but I soon realized it. It doesn’t work with the receiver registered unfortunately.
